# Close socket opened by another application

Tags: c#, sockets

My wpf project connects to a medical machine thru a dll which use a tcp/ip communication. The SDK comes with several useful methods but the "CloseConnection" does not really close the socket previously opened.
While shutting down my main application, the socket is still opened and we've to close it in some way. By far the sdk is pretty outdated, and we cannot get further updates.

How can I close a socket opened by another application?

Comment: How does the socket get opened?  Do you mean the local connection's socket, or the remote connection's socket?

Comment: Local connection's socket